# what is the regex pattern for a regex pattern?

Tags: ruby, regex

What is the regex pattern for a regex pattern? I am using Ruby version 1.8.7, and have a requirement to determine if a given string is a regex pattern. What is the best pattern to use to determine this?

Thanks,
Anand

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think this has been asked before for Ruby regular expressions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

well any word can be a regex pattern.  The string "cat" could be compiled to a regex pattern. You could do something like:

```
def is_regex?(str)
  Regexp.new(str) rescue false
end
```

Comment: There are certain strings which are invalid - for instance, `/(/` is not a valid regex for any regex engine where parentheses are special by default (which is most of them).

Comment: which is my point of doing a Regexp.new.. which will attempt a compile on the str or throw an exception if it cant compile and return false.. are you saying this wont work?

Comment: This is the only sane way to do this :)

Comment: @Jake no, I'm not - I was responding to the the "'is'" bit.

Comment: fair point.. I was using string loosely to say 'word' really.. but definitely any string is not a regex which is why the method would be needed to test for is_regex.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't one, since regexes themselves aren't a regular language (due to things like matching parentheses).

If you want to determine whether something is a valid regex, I'd recommend just trying to compile it as a regex and see if it fails.

Comment: You're very confused. The things people call regular expressions are perfectly capable of match things that aren’t regular languages, including matching parentheses and such.

Comment: Nested parentheses are not something most regex flavors handle nicely. Yes, there are recursive regex engines (such as Perl's recursive reference), but they're really a poor choice in comparison to using an actual regex parser.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the regex pattern is a string with two forward slashes, `/` defining the pattern, then the regex to find a pattern with two foward slashes at the beginning and end of a pattern is as following:

`(\/(?:.)*\/(?:i|g|s|m|U)*)`

Comment: @David: All this regex is required to match is two forward-slashes; everything else is optional.  That's not even sufficient to identify a regex *literal*, and regexes can also be written in the form of string literals (no slashes).  It's not clear to me whether the OP is trying to *locate* regexes or *validate* them, but this regex does neither.

Comment: @Alan: I was just giving an example if the regex was defined literally  as this was the only method I saw possible of finding a regex through regex.

Comment: @Alex: There are some problems with the regex, too.  For example, to match one of several specific characters, a character class is more efficient and readable than an alternation--that is, your `(?:i|g|s|m|U)` should be `[igsmU]`.  Except those modifiers aren't valid; in Ruby 1.8.7 (without the Oniguruma Gem), only `[imox]` are allowed.